# Codeigniter: how can I send a foreach statement to the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Controller:

```
$categorys = array(
    '1234' => array('Car Audio','Car Subwoofers'), 
    '12'   => array('Car Stereos')
)

$category_id = $this->input->get('category_id');
$product_id  = $this->input->get('modelNumber');

if (array_key_exists($category_id,$categorys)) 
{
        foreach($categorys[$category_id] as $key => $value) 
    {
            echo $value;
    }
}
```

How can I echo the **$value** outputted  from the **foreach** statement in my view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```
if (array_key_exists($category_id,$categorys)) 
{
     $query['cats'] = $categorys[$category_id];
}
```

**View**

```
foreach($cats as $key => $value) 
{
   echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the whole array to the view and run the foreach directly in the view, e.g.:

```
$data['array'] = array(/* etc. */);
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

And in the view:

```
<?php foreach($array as $key => $value): ?>
  <p>The key is <?php echo $key; ?><br>
  The value is <?php echo $value; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am doing the foreach in the view, but I would like to keep the logic in the controller, and not have to pass the array to the view file.

Comment: The iteration is something only the view should be concerned with. It is not a logic thing, and does not belong in the controller.